# How to parse a random feed

Tags: android, random, rss, feed

Just wondering how can I parse a random feed from a RSS file, like XKCD Android App for example.

For who don't know the app: You can check latest comic, or move backward/forward or hit random to get a random comic (so I guess the app gets a random feed...)

Thank you all in advance!

Ar.

Comment: Find the first and last and just pull random ones in between.

Answer (score 1):

```c
int getRandomNumber()
{
    return 4;  // chosen by fair dice roll.
               // guaranteed to be random.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XKCD comics are numbered. The "random" feed probably just generates a random number within the range of currently-published comics and fetches that numbered comic.

Comment: Thanks unluddite, it was implicit in my original post, but I don't know how to get and old feed. When I parse a RSS I get, let's say, the last 10 posts, but I don't know how to get older ones. 

Anyone can point me to any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try going on your wifi network on your phone, and use Wireshark to snoop the request that the app is making. This may give a clue as to where the request is being sent to and what it looks like.